# Can the Cartesian Product of two non-open sets be open?

Tags: general-topology

The Cartesian product of open sets is open, and the Cartesian product of closed sets is closed.

But, can the Cartesian product of two sets which are not open be an open set?

Or, will the Cartesian product of two non-open sets be non-open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** The projection map from $X\times Y$ to $X$ (or $Y$) is an open map.

Comment: OK, admittedly I had to look up some definitions here, but what I gather is that projecting an open X x Y into X means that X is open. However, by the same reasoning, Y is also open. So if X x Y is open, it requires that BOTH X and Y be open?

Comment: Yes, the point is that $U$ equals to its projection from $U\times V$. (I used $X$ and $Y$ to denote the ambient spaces.)

Comment: OK, thank you. So it is in fact correct to say that A x B is open iff A and B are open.

Comment: Most indeededly.

Answer (score 2):

Sets of the form $U\times V$ with $U$ open in $X$ and $V$ open in $Y$ form a basis for the product topology on $X\times Y$.

So let $A\times B$ be open, and let $a\times b\in A\times B$. Then there is such a basic set $U\times V$ with $a\times b\in U\times V\subset A\times B$.

This means that $a\in U\subset A$ and $b\in V\subset B$. Since $a$ and $b$ were arbitrary, this shows $A$ and $B$ are open.